# The useState becomes read-only after the data is saved to Redux toolkit

Tags: redux

After the useState is push to the redux toolkit, the setState error is reported
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '#'

```
//Data transferred to Redux
const [listData,setListData] = useState({orderItem: []})

 //Because the subscript is used for positioning, the array length may be 2 for example item:[item:[{.....xxx}]]
const [notepadList,setNotepadList] = useState([0])


const dispatch = useDispatch();

const submit = ()=>{
   dispatch(changeNameArr(listData))
}

const changeName = () =>{
    let temp = orderListData;
     if (notepadList[1] === undefined) {
       temp.orderItem[notepadList[0]].price = value;
     } else {
       temp.orderItem[notepadList[0]].orderItemsOptions[notepadList[1]].price = value;
     }
     setOrderListData(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(temp)));
}
```

```
changeNameArr:(state,action)=>{
  state.list.push(action.payload)
}
```

After clicking Submit, an error occurs after clicking ChangeName. There is no error before clicking Submit

Error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '#'

I tried to modify the writing method of setState and changeNameArr, but they did not work or reported an error

```
const changeName = () =>{
setOrderListData((prev) => {
      if (notepadList[1] === undefined) {
        prev.orderItem[notepadList[0]].price = value;
      } else {
        prev.orderItem[notepadList[0]].orderItemsOptions[notepadList[1]].price = value;
      }
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prev));
    });
}
```

```
changeNameArr:(state,{payload})=>{
  return {...state,list:{...payload}}
}
```

This method can be executed normally when you just enter the page, but it fails to execute this method again after the data is saved to the Redux toolkit

I hope you can help me solve this problem

Comment: Can you edit the post to include the complete error message and code stacktrace? It's unclear where exactly the issue lies. BTW, you've a state mutation in the `changeName` handler.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain the problem clearly. I'll replace the problem and describe it again. Would you please look at it again.

Comment: What is `orderListData` and `setOrderListData`, React state and setter? The `changeName` handler is still mutating an object, `orderListData`. It's still not clear exactly where the error is occurring without a complete error message and stacktrace. I'm curious though, why the state duplication between the redux store and this component? We may actually need a more complete and comprehensive [mcve].

Comment: I found the problem is that when I modify the content of the array in the useState object array, if I directly change the value in the useState object, it can be saved normally, but when I modify the value in the object array, I probably know where the error is, but if I don't use this method to modify the content in the orderItem array, how do I need to modify the value in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Redux state and React state should always be handled as readonly - you should always create a copy with a change and never change the original.

Your code here,

```js
 let temp = arr
 arr.push({name:2})
```

does not create a copy of `arr`.

It creates a new variable `temp` that **points to** `arr`.
And no matter if you do `temp.push` and `arr.push`, you change both.

Usually, this wouldn't surface (until it becomes a very subtle bug later on), but since you put that same reference into Redux (and Redux takes steps to prevent accidental mutation), you now notice it - that change would not only change `temp` and `arr`, but also your Redux state.

So actually, you have to create a new copy instead of just pushing:

```js
setArr(prev => [...prev, {name: 2}])
```

or

```js
setArr(prev => {
  const next = [...prev] // create a new array as a shallow copy, not a reference. All the objects *inside* that array are still references to the old array elements, but the array itself is new and you can now add new elements
  next.push({name: 2}) // now you can push because it is not state anywhere yet
  return next // return it - now it becomes state and you should not modify it any more
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain the problem clearly. I'll replace the problem and describe it again. Would you please look at it again

Comment: The specific trigger condition is that the content in useState is modified after saving to the redux toolkit, which causes such problems. Before saving, using these functions will not cause such problems

Comment: @user19539777 My main point is that **in React you are not allowed to modify something that is in `useState`**. This might have accidentally worked, but it goes against the rules of React's `useState`. You can never just `.push` on something in `useState` or do any other mutation. You always have to create a modified copy and save that back to your state.
So your problem is currently surfacing because of RTK, but it is just showing you a bug in your code.

Comment: So, in your case, your `prev.orderItem[notepadList[0]].price = ...`  will modify **the last** React state. That is not allowed. It is also not allowed in Redux state. Redux is just more strict about it - but it might totally also cause bugs if you do this only in React. You have to write immutable updates.

Comment: I tried the method you mentioned. If I change the value in the useState object directly, it can be saved normally, but I modify the value in the object array. I probably know where the error is. But if I don't use this method, how do I modify the value in the orderItem array

Comment: You are not going to enjoy writing an update this many levels deep in a way that doesn't mutate anything: `prev.orderItem[notepadList[0]].orderItemsOptions[notepadList[1]].price`. You want to move those sorts of updates into your redux toolkit reducers where it is okay to modify objects directly.  Instead of passing the entire updated array as your action payload, think about what "action" actually occurred and what's the minimal amount of data that you need to represent that action.  You want to wind up with code like `dispatch(changePrice({ itemId: 123, price: 99 }))`.

Comment: You can also look into the `immer` library for immutably creating new values outside of RTK reducers - that's what RTK uses internally.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I solved this problem with Immer. I just started front-end development. Thank you for your help